# Edible supports for a fondant palm tree

Tags: fondant

I am working on a zoo themed cake for a 2 year old. I have made all the animals and added a piece of spaghetti through the body and attached the head on it to keep everything edible on the cake as its a kids' cake. I do not want to add toothpicks or wires as they are not edible. I now want to make a palm tree (about 10-15 cm). I have been looking on the web and all the tutorials ask for wires or dowels for support.

Can someone please suggest what else could I use as an edible support to make a fondant palm tree?

P.S. It could also be used as a support for other tall fondant figurines.

Comment: I don't see how a 2-year-old encountering a piece of raw spaghetti in the cake is any better than said 2-year-old encountering a wooden dowel. Neither is edible, but at least the latter is unlikely to break when bitten.

Comment: @Marti: Thanks for your comment. It is the linguini that I am using and is a replacement to a toothpick. It is still edible and easy enough to break, if the figurine was to be eaten, which the kids do. It is better than putting non edible things on the cake, at least in my view. I know that spaghetti won't be able to hold longer structures like a tree and hence my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretzel sticks sound promising! The normal sized ones aren't quite 10-15cm, but there are longer ones out there. You could also look for Pocky or some other kind of cookie stick - sometimes things like that are sold as edible coffee stirrers (maybe coated with chocolate).

If you can't find any of that, it should all be easy enough to make yourself; pretty much any crispy cracker or cookie, rolled out into thin sticks instead of its normal shape, should get you started.

Comment: I bought a mint filled chocolate stick and will be using it to create the support.

Answer (score 4):

For something a little more durable than pretzels or cookies, I generally suggest candy canes, especially if you can find the un-bent 'peppermint stick' style.  Unfortunately, they're a little harder to come by at this time of year.

You might also be able to glue together a bunch of spaghetti or linguini to make it stronger ... either use egg whites or a flour paste, coat the pasta, then tie it together in a bundle and let dry for a day or two.

Comment: That's a great idea. Will try it next time. +1. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make them out of fondant, and then freeze them, Make sure you have extra long tree trunks

When you are ready to serve, poke in the palms and candles and no problem

Kids like frozen fondant too!

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned that its for someone else's kid and I will be transporting the cake, which is 30-45 minutes away. So freezing might not be a good idea this time. Like your idea otherwise +1

Comment: Will still work, use an insulated container and ice packs, they wont defrost that fast